# wrapping a function as a jQuery parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, coding-style

i am buliding an autocomplete for my website when i came across this style of building code:

```
$(function() {

    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $(element).autocomplete(....

    //more code
});
```

i know about closures, "IIFE"s but this one's a new one for me.

- what's with the "jQuery-wrapped" code above?
- is there any particular reason i should do that? (scope?)
- optimization-wise, should i even do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$(function() { });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {});` and as before it executes once the DOM has been ready.
2. Defining a function inside is to tell that, the function is only available once the dom is ready to execute.
3. `$(element).autocomplete(....` is simply implementing the plugin to the selector, once the DOM is ready to execute.

Hope its clear now :)

---

`$(function() {` or `$(document).ready(function() {` does not need the whole page to load, to run as `$(window).load(fn)` does.

Comment: thanks! never knew that it was just a shorthand to `.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

`$(fn)` or `$(document).ready(fn)` Is jQuery's onload/onDOMContentLoaded handler. The function passed to it is executed once the DOM on the page is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in `$(function() { }` will be executed after the DOM has loaded. I prefer to use
`$(document).ready(function() { }` because it is more clear.